# Facybox ajax link: The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

So I have two links one to register an account and one to get a password reminder:

Password reminder works, register link does not.

here is the code for the links:

```
<h4 class="register"><a href="<?=base_url() ?>auth/register" class="register fancybox.ajax">Register</a></h4>
<h4><a href="<?=base_url() ?>auth/forgot_password" class="register fancybox.ajax">Forgot your password?</a></h4>
```

When I look at the rendered links through firebug, they look exactly the same apart from an additional class on one of the h4 elements, I can copy the links and visit them through the browser but as I say one does not work through fancybox.

Any suggestions why this might be?

Comment: I suspect that only the link `<a>` should have the class `register`, not the `h4` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that only the link `<a>` should have the class `register`, not the `h4` tag.

Why? because you are binding fancybox to the selector `.register`, aren't you? so fancybox is expecting to find the source of content from the `h4` tag in the first instance, which shares the same class as the link.

Comment: Spot on... That has been driving me mad.